# How to create a button with several commands (hangman game) in visual basic 2019

Tags: vb.net, button, windows-forms-designer

I want to make a hangman game in visual basic 2019. I have a button for each letter, if it's the right letter it will appear on the unknown word but if it's the worng letter I want to click in the button and the hangman body part will appear. My problem is to program which body part of him will appear.
I'm a really begginer in visual basic, so please help me with easy terms that I will understand. thank you.

my body parts are pictureboxes. the first one is the hang thing with the head. the second picture box is exactly the same plus th belly part. the third one is the same as the previous one plus onde arm, ...
I was trying to put all in the same button like

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If CABEÇA.Visible = True Then
            TRONCO.Visible = True
            CABEÇA.Visible = False
        Else
            CABEÇA.Visible = True
        End If
        If TRONCO.Visible = True Then
            TRONCO.Visible = False
            BESQ.Visible = True
        Else TRONCO.Visible = True
        End If
        If BESQ.Visible = True Then
            BESQ.Visible = False
            BDIR.Visible = True
        End If
        If BDIR.Visible = True Then
            BDIR.Visible = False
            PESQ.Visible = True
        End If
        If PESQ.Visible = True Then
            PESQ.Visible = False
            PDIR.Visible = True
            MessageBox.Show("you lost")
        End If
    End Sub
```

cabeça=head; tronco=belly, besq=left arm, bdir= right arm, pesq=left leg, pdir= right leg

this scheme is not possible, off course, because or it will give the head or it will pass trhough the code and give me the last image.
Is there any way of making each image appear once I click the button (first click-first image, second clicks-second one, third click-third one)
If not, I'm open to different suggestions.

Comment: You can think of the "body" as a score out of 6. So, 1 / 6 = the head, 2 / 6 = the belly etc. Keep a form level variable with the _current_ score (1 or 2 or 3). When they click, add to the score, and show the corresponding picture.

Answer (score 0):

Set all of your pictures to visible=false at the beginning of the program and add the following to your button event:

```
    If cabeça.Visible = False Then
        cabeça.Visible = True
    ElseIf tronco.Visible = False Then
        tronco.Visible = True
    ElseIf besq.Visible = False Then
        besq.Visible = True
    ElseIf bdir.Visible = False Then
        bdir.Visible = True
    ElseIf pesq.Visible = False Then
        pesq.Visible = True
    ElseIf pdir.Visible = False Then
        pdir.Visible = True
        MsgBox("You lose!")
    Else
        MsgBox("Game Over")
    End If
```